# JPGraph wont display when trying to use oracle database data

Tags: php, oracle, jpgraph

Currently trying to display some data from a database in JPGraph. The JPGraph displays when putting data in manually but when trying to use a variable it no longer displays.

I'm still learning how to use oracle as i'm more used to MySQL so the error could lie in how I have tried to retrieve the oracle data.

Any advice?

Here is the php used:

```
<?php // content="text/plain; charset=utf-8"

$conn = oci_connect('Username', 'Groupassignment2020', 'db_link');

if (!$conn) {   

$e = oci_error();   

trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);

}

$selectBudget = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT BUDGET FROM REVENUE");
oci_execute($selectBudget);

require_once ('src/jpgraph.php');
require_once ('src/jpgraph_bar.php');

$data1y=array($selectBudget);

// Create the graph. These two calls are always required
$graph = new Graph(1400,800,'auto');
$graph->SetScale("textlin");

$theme_class=new UniversalTheme;
$graph->SetTheme($theme_class);

$graph->yaxis->SetTickPositions(array(0,30,60,90,120,150), array(15,45,75,105,135));
$graph->SetBox(false);

$graph->ygrid->SetFill(false);
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels(array('A','B','C','D'));
$graph->yaxis->HideLine(false);
$graph->yaxis->HideTicks(false,false);

// Create the bar plots
$b1plot = new BarPlot($data1y);
$b2plot = new BarPlot($data2y);
$b3plot = new BarPlot($data3y);

// Create the grouped bar plot
$gbplot = new GroupBarPlot(array($b1plot,$b2plot,$b3plot));
// ...and add it to the graPH
$graph->Add($gbplot);


$b1plot->SetColor("white");
$b1plot->SetFillColor("#768692");

$b2plot->SetColor("white");
$b2plot->SetFillColor("#0072CE");

$b3plot->SetColor("white");
$b3plot->SetFillColor("#41B6E6");

$graph->title->Set("Bar Plots");

// Display the graph
$graph->Stroke();
?>
```

Comment: You haven't qualified the name of the table (`REVENUE`) with a schema name. This may be OK, as long as the schema in which the table resides is that same as the user name you're logging on with. If that's not the case you will need to qualify the name of the table with the name of the schema, e.g. `OTHERUSER.REVENUE`. Also, you should be checking for errors after your calls to e.g. `oci_parse` and `oci_execute`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I believe the database connection is correct. What would be the best way of checking for errors related to oci_parse and oci_execute? We're currently using this for a web application and are not too sure how to debug errors related to Oracle.

Comment: According the [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-parse.php) `oci_parse` returns FALSE if there's an error. Then it appears that you can use [oci_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-error.php) to retrieve the last error.

Comment: Check out Oracle's free [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html).The back half is still relevant. Page 161 shows how to handle parse and execute errors.  You can debug using your favorite PHP debugger, or use basic `var_dump()` (or similar) calls to check code flow the hard way.